# How can I make my computer trust a firewall web server certificate?

Tags: ssl

Every time I log into my firewall I get a message that says:

> The site's security certificate is not trusted!

I know this is because my firewall doesn't have an identity certificate from a trusted CA (and I don't want to generate one for it because it's pretty expensive). I'd like to make my firewall create a self-signed CA which it will then apply to the web GUI. I then want to add it to my trusted CAs list on my browser so I stop getting this warning.

I've set up the self-signed cert on the Palo Alto but there's no option to "export" that certificate as a root certificate to my browser.

The firewall is a Palo Alto 3020 running PAN-OS 6.

Comment: What browser are you using?  You should be able to install the self-signed cert into your trusted certificate store for the browser you're using to access the web-gui.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with that brand of firewall, but I assume you can import an SSL certificate into it. This thread talks about a couple of different ways to generate self signed SSL certs - [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346512/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-selfssl) that should do the job.